# How to accurately mix RGB colors

Tags: rgb

I'm a bit of a newbie here but if anyone knows the method to combine two RGB colors and get a precise result (additive).

Comment: Have you tried arithmetic addition? for ex. RGB(1,2,3) and RGB(5,6,7) mixed would give RGB(1+5, 2+6, 3+7) i.e. RGB(6, 8, 10). Painting tools and layers in graphic programs have blending modes. For ex. GIMP and Photoshop can make the shown RGB addition between two layers if the upper layer has blending mode ADD. The layers stay intact, only the shown color is mix by adding. Painting tools with blending mode ADD make the addition to the existing color and the original is lost.

Comment: Accurate how? What are yiu trying to accomplish

Comment: Ill give my scenario, I have two RGB values. The first is combined with another value (the unknown) to make the second. I know the first and the second values, but not the unknown. I need to find the unknown.

Comment: Well ask that question then, you can edit the question. You havent given anything to work with.  Anyway when we talk about calculation on colors you need to be aware that colors are not numbers. So you need to make distinction between color as data, and colors as color representations. Both can be calculated on but they both give different results.